# I got a dependency in my pom which is in conflict with a other

Tags: java, maven, runtime-error

Now theres a conflict in my pom, we already have the jersery-container-servlet and I'm using the dependency from paymill in my pom which is this one:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.paymill</groupId>
      <artifactId>paymill-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

now theres a conflict between those two and at the end it seems like all h2k-locator and h2k-api is ommited and therefore I get multiple errors.....

is there a way in eclipse I could solve this because I want to use the h2k-locator and h2k-api from my jersey-container-servlet since its a newer version

Comment: h2k-locator and h2k-api are coming from other dependency as well apart from jersey-container-servlet? If yes, then exclude them from other dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the maven exclude mechanism.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.paymill</groupId>
      <artifactId>paymill-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
          <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
          <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 

    </dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for your nice advice so far but now I have this error: `Authenticator.invoke() failedjava.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method java.lang.String.length() of a null object loaded from local variable 'name'`

Comment: It is hard to say without the complete stacktrace and the code you are using. Maybe paymill is not compatible with the newer hk2 version

Comment: so I have to exclude the newer versions of hk2 ?

Comment: Maybe this works, or you have to search for a other Version of paymill which is compatible to newer hj2 version